# Setting a minimum height on an empty flexbox item doesn't expand the height of the parent in IE 11

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a dashboard to display some high-level financial information, and I'm having trouble getting the layout to display correctly in IE11. The information is displayed as a "Card" (a la Material Design), with the elements within said card being positioned using `flexbox`.

Here is how the design looks in Firefox:

[image: Firefox Card]

And here is that same design, rendered in IE11:

[image]

Here is the HTML to layout the card:

```
<section class="card pointer">
  <div class="card__body">
    <div class="flex-row">

      <!-- The left column, consisting only the "Pay Date" information -->
      <div class="flex-row__item">
        <div class="group-v">
          <div class="group-v__item">
            <h3 class="card__text--heading">Pay Date</h3>
          </div>

          <div class="group-v__item">
            <p class="card__text">Fri 04/01/16</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- The right column, consisting of the "Events" and "Dollar Amt" information -->
      <div class="flex-row__item">
        <div class="flex-col">

          <!-- Events -->
          <div class="flex-col__item">
            <div class="group-v">
              <div class="group-v__item">
                <h3 class="card__text--heading text__align-right">Events</h3>
              </div>

              <div class="group-v__item">
                <p class="card__text text__align-right">45</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="flex-col--empty"></div>

          <!-- Dollar Amt -->
          <div class="flex-col__item">
            <div class="group-v">
              <div class="group-v__item">
                <h3 class="card__text--heading text__align-right">Dollar Amt</h3>
              </div>

              <div class="group-v__item">
                <p class="card__text text__align-right">$1.99</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

The space in the middle of the card is achieved by the `flex-row--empty` element. I wasn't able to figure out a way to get the `card__body` element to expand to the height of the parent `card` element if I set a `min-height`, so I instead decided to achieve the same effect with a space.

Unfortunately, IE11 doesn't seem to want to expand the parent element in order to properly render the card. What is a good workaround in order to have IE render the card in the same way as Firefox?

For reference, below is the relevant SASS for the `flex-row` and `flex-col` classes:

```
.flex-row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    min-height: 2rem;
    width: 100%;

    &--compact {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
        min-height: 2rem;
        width: 100%;
    }

    &:last-child {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    &--empty {
        min-height: 2rem;
    }

    &__item {
        flex: 1;
        text-align: center;

        &:first-of-type {
            margin-right: 0.5rem;
            text-align: left;
        }

        &:last-of-type {
            margin-left: 0.5rem;
            text-align: right;
        }

        &:only-of-type {
            margin: 0;
            text-align: left;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#3-min-height-on-a-flex-container-wont-apply-to-its-flex-items

Comment: Who cares about IE ;)

Comment: @KevinJantzer I wish that I didn't have to, believe me! But it's an officially supported browser here, so I have to account for it.

Comment: I'm butting up against some IE flexbox issues. Just wondering if you'd found a fix for this

Comment: @Chao Hey, I'm sorry for not responding so quickly. I did find a fix for this. To work around IE11, you have to set both a height and width for the parent elements that you're working on. I followed the link that Michael_B commented, and that helped out a lot! Feel free to reach out later on if you have more specific questions about it.